# Retuning locally allocated object in C++ 2003

Tags: c++, stack, allocation, c++03

I get a bad feeling about this code

```
widget* GetNewWidget()
{
   widget* theWidget = (widget *) malloc(sizeof(widget));
   return theWidget;
}
```

Firstly, one should never cast the result of malloc()   (nor, I suspect, use it in C++ (?)).

Secondly, won't `theWidget` be allocated on the stack?

If so, won't the caller trying to access after this function returns be undefined behaviour?

Can someone point to an authoritative URL explaining this?

---

[Update] I am thinking of this question [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: malloc allocate memory on heap, just as new. You are right, it's avoidable in C++.

Comment: Yes, malloc allocates on the heap (+1), but the returned variable was local to the function and so was allocated on the stack - is that not a problem?

Comment: Yes, `theWidget` is a local variable, but after the function called, it will be copied to the outside variable. e.g. `widget* p = GetNewWidget();` Now `p` points to the memory malloced, you can use it safely.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Because of restriction to C++03 (in 2015!) and the fact that the code posted is really bad C++, as an alternative solution you could at least consider, changing the job itself.

Comment: I do - on a daily basis. Until now I have stayed here, setting an example - documentation, coding, reviewing, unit test ...

Comment: Behavior is defined here, you return by value (a pointer, which is basically an integer value of address). It's the same that if you returned an int.

Comment: Note that this doesn't call the constructor of `widget`, if it has one. The memory is uninitialized.

Comment: @Drop - ah, that makes it perfectly clear. Feel free to post it as an answer (d'oh!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In summary: this code is perfectly fine

Returning a pointer is like returning an `int`: the very act of returning creates a bitwise copy.

### Step, by step, the code works as follows:

1. `malloc(sizeof(widget));`

   Allocates a block of memory on the heap[1], starting at some address (let's call it *a*), and `sizeof(widget)` bytes long.
2. `widget* theWidget = (widget *) malloc(sizeof(widget));`

   Stores the address *a* on the stack[2] in the variable `theWidget`. If `malloc` allocated a block at address`0x00001248`, then `theWidget` now contains the value `0x00001248`, as if it were an integer.
3. `return theWidget;`

   Now causes the **value** of *a* to be returned, i.e., the value `0x00001248` gets written to wherever the return value is expected.

At no point is the address of `theWidget` used. Hence, there is no risk of accessing a dangling pointer to `theWidget`. Note that if your code would `return &theWidget;`, there would have been an issue.

[1] Or it might fail, and return `NULL`

[2] Or it might keep it in a register

Answer (score 1):

On the stack you just allocated a pointer, it's not related to the object itself. :)

I never use malloc (it's a C thing, you shouldn't use it in C++), thus i am not sure, but i hardly believe it's undefined behaviour.

If you would write this: `widget* theWidget = new widget();` it should work correctly.

Even better if you use smart pointers if you have C++11

```
std::unique_ptr<widget> GetNewWidget()
{
   std::unique_ptr<widget> theWidget(std::make_unique<widget>());
   return theWidget;
}
```

Or in this case you can write even smaller code, like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<widget> GetNewWidget()
{
   return std::make_unique<widget>();
}
```

The above version will clean out the memory as soon as unique pointer go out of scope. (unless you move it to another unique_ptr) It's worth some time to read about memory management in C++11.

Comment: Thanks . I am looking at someone else's code and wondering whether it is undefined behaviour as it stands. Alas, we are restricted to C++03.  It is still not clear to me, even with your answer, if it would be undefined (or dangerous) behaviour to access that return after return.

Comment: You allocate a memory on the heap for your object, it's not related to the stack. On the stack you just have a pointer. As long as you use heap allocated object you shouldn't care about stacks, it's defined. You can have several pointer to the same heap object. This would be problematic only if you would allocate the object on the stack and return a pointer to it, so like:
`widget myWidget;
return &myWidget;`
This would crash as soon as you try to use this reference cause you would have a reference to a deleted object. In heap you don't have such a problem as long as you don't free it.

Comment: I think that I am missing your point, sorry. I do understand that the actual memory here is on the heap. However, where I fear a problem is that the pointer to it is on the stack (variable theWidget ). Won't that pointer go out of scope when the function reruns, leaving the allocated memory with nothing reliably pointing to it?

Comment: That's why you return the pointer. If you call this function like this: `widget* widgetptr = GetNewWidget();` then you have a copy of the pointer to the heap allocated object, which you can use. It's absolutely okay. If you just call this function without storing the return value, so for some unknown reason you write something like: `if(GetNewWidget()) {blablabla}` then you would have a memory leak, but it's still defined and won't crash.

Comment: It's the scenario i wrote that would crash... in the code you wrote you don't return a pointer to a local variable, you return a pointer to a heap object...

Comment: Agreed - BUT the pointer itself is on the stack and goes out of scope at the end of the function - surely the caller cannot be guaranteed access to it after the function returns.

Comment: It would be undefined behaviour if someone tried to use the `malloc`'d space as if it contained a real `widget`, and widget is not trivially constructible

Comment: @Mawg the caller accesses a copy of the pointer, not the original pointer. This function returns by value which means that the caller receives a copy of the expression being `return`ed. It is no different to `int x() { return 5; }`